# How can I get the value of the specific value in the xml file?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, apache-nifi

I keep getting no result, even when using local-name() to retrieve an xml value.

I'm working with NiFi (apache 1.9.2) and having what I think is probably a problem with namespaces. I have an XML file that I am receiving that looks like:

```
<RCV_MSG xmlns="data" dateread="2019/02/13">
  <METADATA>
    <TEXT Name="filename">C:\transmit\241</TEXT>
    <TEXT Name="code">8EAFB40</TEXT>
  </METADATA>
</RCV_MSG>
```

I'm trying to use the EvaluateXPath processor to send the value 8EAFB40 to the flow file.

The content of the fields in the processor:

```
Destination: flowfile-content
Return Type: string
Validate DTD: false
extract (the manditory added) : //*[local-name()-'METADATA']
```

I know the last field "extract" is the problem ... that returns both of the TEXT values, i.e.:

```
C:\transmit\241
8EAFB40
```

I've tried a ton of different ways of getting *just* the second line, but so far it has been fruitless (I get empty results). BTW, this is reduced from the real problem set ... I can't just grab the 2nd line and be done with it. I really need to extract the XML.

Comment: Can you try this xpath expression? `*//TEXT[2]`

Comment: I had already tried that ... :( But I can't be *positive* it will always be the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't want to deal with namespaces, you can use this XPath:

```
//*[local-name() = 'METADATA']/*[@Name = 'code']
```

or to make it more precise, you can use `namespace-uri()` function, e.g.:

```
//*[local-name() = 'METADATA' and namespace-uri() = 'data']/*[@Name = 'code']
```

Comment: If I *had* to deal with namespaces (e.g., if there were multiple namespaces in the XML) is there something that would allow selection of the namespace as well?

That is beyond what I need for this, but I've done Java that had to deal with differing namespaces in the 
XML. What I think I need is a good reference for XPath expressions. 
But again, *THANK YOU*.

Comment: @BrianWithnell, you can use `namespace-uri()` function, e.g: `//*[local-name() = 'METADATA' and namespace-uri() = 'data']/*[@Name = 'code']`

Comment: @Krill Polishchuk, Thanks again. That makes it compete (at least for what I'm doing).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just a little more refinement ... if you have to make sure it is exactly the path in the example:

```
/*[local-name()='RCV_MSG']/*[local-name()='METADATA']/*[local-name()='TEXT' and @Name='code']
```

More explicit ... but still doesn't specify namespace.